# ERROR AppError: Can't find /bundle.js.map on this server

Tags: node.js, bundler, parcel

I'm using parcel bundle in my node app but the Axios did not work and it shows me these errors:
also,bundle.js.map can not be found.

```
ERROR ?? AppError: Can't find /favicon.ico on this server!
at G:\NODE-APP\my-node.js\exp-2\exp\app.js:94:8
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (G:\NODE-APP\my-node.js\exp-2\exp\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (G:\NODE-APP\my-node.js\exp-2\exp\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
at next (G:\NODE-APP\my-node.js\exp-2\exp\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:14)
at next (G:\NODE-APP\my-node.js\exp-2\exp\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:14)
at next (G:\NODE-APP\my-node.js\exp-2\exp\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:14)
at next (G:\NODE-APP\my-node.js\exp-2\exp\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:14)
at next (G:\NODE-APP\my-node.js\exp-2\exp\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:14)
at next (G:\NODE-APP\my-node.js\exp-2\exp\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:14)
at Route.dispatch (G:\NODE-APP\my-node.js\exp-2\exp\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (G:\NODE-APP\my-node.js\exp-2\exp\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at G:\NODE-APP\my-node.js\exp-2\exp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
at param (G:\NODE-APP\my-node.js\exp-2\exp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:354:14)
at param (G:\NODE-APP\my-node.js\exp-2\exp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:365:14)
at Function.process_params (G:\NODE-APP\my-node.js\exp-2\exp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:410:3)
at next (G:\NODE-APP\my-node.js\exp-2\exp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
```

[image of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3Prg.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Your requesting favicon.ico image(the small image on top of your app). and it seems that you don't have it/you're requesting it in the wrong place.

Comment: is it a deployed project or a local one?

Comment: it's a local one.

Comment: on the front yes? wich tech are you using? can you add the place where you ask for the favico?

Comment: node.js `img(src='/img/logo-white.png'`  `app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/public`));`

Comment: that's not what I'm searching for, have you a git repo?

Comment: ` link(rel='shortcut icon' type='image/png' href='/img/favicon.png')`

Comment: '/img/favicon.png') it's simply not finding it, maybe it's searching in your public folder.

Comment: I have this to link the files `app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));` `script(src='/js/bundle.js')`